# I can't open anything with Selenium WebBrowser Java

Tags: java, file, selenium

I am trying to open local files with Selenium. With the code below, Firefox is opening, but I have the error `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.`.

```
    File gecko = new File("resources/geckodriver64.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", gecko.getAbsolutePath());

    FirefoxOptions capabilities = new FirefoxOptions();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

    driver.get("file:///C:/example/myfile.pdf");
```

Can someone help me ? I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

We have now come to the part where you will see how you can use GeckoDriver to launch Firefox. You will first need to download GeckoDriver and then set its path. There are three different ways to use GeckoDriver with Selenium 3:

With setting system properties in the test
With setting system properties by Environment Variable
With setting up Browser Desired Capabilities

Download Gecko Driver:-
1- Gecko Driver different versions can be downloaded from Github. I suggest you to use the latest version.

Set System Properties for Gecko Driver:-
Code to set the System properties is System.setProperty(“webdriver.gecko.driver”,”Path to geckodriver.exe”);

The complete program to launch the GeckoDriver will be like this:

```
package seleniumPrograms;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class Gecko_Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\\\XXXX\\trunk\\Library\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com");

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: Sure, thank you for your answer, but I already did that, check the 2 firsts lines of my code. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check Below answer. This is working solution on my machine. Please check your firefox version too.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
public class geckodriver {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

             System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
           Thread.sleep(5000);
//           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
//            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
//           
//           WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

           capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
           capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
           capabilities.setVersion("your firefox version");
           capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
           capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);

           WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver(capabilities);

             driver.get("http://www.google.com");

             Thread.sleep(5000);
             driver.quit();
}}
```

Comment: I tried, the result is the same, moreover `new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);` is deprecated. I have this log during the execution :

INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`

Comment: Sure, here are logs :
`sept. 27, 2018 12:29:09 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
INFO: Using new FirefoxOptions() is preferred to DesiredCapabilities.firefox()
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code ?

```
    package seleniumPrograms;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    public class Gecko_Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I set marionette to true, I have the following error log : `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`

Comment: @Azrix: I have modified my code. Can you please check ?

Comment: Sure, it tells me that it's better to use `new FirefoxOptions()`, and I still have the `SessionNotCreatedException` :/

Comment: Which version of firefox are you using?

Comment: 45.0, I don't have choice for that unfortunately

Comment: This is the 0.22.0, i downloaded it on their GitHub [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: If I could find a solution for this version of firefox, it would be perfect, apart from that, it's good

Comment: Or else try to change your selenium  to version 2.53.1 and use below code: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        Thread.sleep(5000);